# How to force php to evaluate "011" as "11" and not "9"

Tags: php

a single line of code :

```
echo eval("return 011");
```

the output is `9` because PHP think 011 is an octal value : Ok.
Now, how to force php to evaluate "011" as "11" ?

Comment: It's not octal it is decimal value.

Comment: I can't think of a *sane* way… but I can't think of a reason why you would be evaluating PHP but not wanting to do so following the normal rules of PHP. This sounds horribly like an XY problem.

Comment: There's no way to force it from such expression. You must change something within evaluated `return 011` line to achieve different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `+` operator to turn a string into a regular number; its operation is similar to doing an `(int)` [type cast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) or by calling [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval).

```
$x = '011';

echo +$x; // 11
```

The real question is why your code has an `eval()` in the first place. Apart from modifying the string before it's evaluated, there's nothing much you could do about that.

#### Update

If you're evaluating a mathematical expression, you could remove any leading zeroes before integer values like so:

```
$x = '5 * 011';
$x = preg_replace('/(?<=[^\d.]|^)0(?=\d+)/', '', $x); // "5 * 11"
```

Comment: why eval : because `$x` can be an arithmetic expression.

Comment: @Apolo I suppose that's fair; could you share a little more code about how that would come about?

Comment: For some reasons I can't share the code, but just for you to try it : imagine you have an array full of arithmetic expressions and numbers can have leading zeroes. You want the result of every expressions in a new array.

Comment: @Apolo I've updated my answer to reflect something that might work for you.

Comment: @Apollo Who writes decimal `11` in such way? Shouldn't `011` be considered as octal? This could be actually desired functionality.

Comment: @doc I must deal with it

Comment: @apolo they're look around assertions, i.e. match 0 if not preceded by another digit or period and if followed by another digit ( to prevent removing a single 0

Comment: Your regular expression performs weird if value is in brackets, i.e. `5 * (-001 + 2)` -> `5 * (-01 + 2)`.

Comment: @doc that's not weird, it just doesn't deal with multiple consecutive zeroes; not sure whether that's a requirement though.

Comment: Ah true, dunno how I've seen it removing consecutive zeroes :o. Must be tired.

Comment: I hope this time my eyes are not fooling me. `011 * 5` -> `011 * 5`

Comment: BTW is unary `+` operator (`+$x`) documented somewhere? I can't see it in PHP manual.

Comment: @doc Ugh yes, missing `^` in the look behind, will edit when I get back to my desk

Comment: @doc The unary use of `+` is like the `-` in the sense that you can think of it as an imaginary `0` on one side of the operator.

Comment: @Jack I modified your regex to `'/(?<!\d)0(?=\d+)/'` yours wasn't working for 0 at the start of the expression. eg. with '011' :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) ?

```
<?php echo intval('011');// will return 11?>
```

Comment: Note that intval(011) would still return decimal 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo eval("return (int)'011';");
```

Or what about changing it to:

```
echo eval("return 11;");
```

But if you want it to return 9 without changing the code itself, no this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `(int)` to change the data type to integer.

```
echo (int)'011';
```