# XML to JSON convertor

Tags: json, xml

Was looking at a few questions in SO for a good solution for XML to JSON convertors. I Chanced upon this :
[Convert xml to json with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451370/convert-xml-to-json-with-java)
This seemed to work fine for almost all of our scenarios but for the issue below!
I noticed whenever I we have an XML such as this (zero followed by a number)

```
<a>011</a>
```

this seems to be getting formatted to

```
{a:9}
```

However this seems to work fine

```
<a>11</a>
```

Whcih gets formatted to

```
{a:11}
```

This is the simple code I am using:

```
String sXML = "<a>011</a>";
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(sXML);
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it thinks it's an octal value, which is why you get 9, see the following article which has a similar problem:

1. [How to force php to evaluate "011" as "11" and not "9"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608480/how-to-force-php-to-evaluate-011-as-11-and-not-9)
2. [When displaying the value of variable "int a = 011", I get 9. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615960/when-displaying-the-value-of-variable-int-a-011-i-get-9-why)